# Windows XP Update site is not working

Tags: windows-xp

I have Windows XP SP3 and IE8. When I go to windowsupdate.microsoft.com it redirects to go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkId=209191 and "Internet Explorer cannot display webpage". I also installed Windows Update Agent 7.4(`WindowsUpdateAgent30-x86.exe`) but not fixed

Do not advertise me to upgrade Windows because I installed on VM on purpose

Comment: Windows update site for XP has not worked for many years, if you have automatic updates turned on you will get a notification icon in the sys tray when updates are available.

Comment: In Firefox, windowsupdate.microsoft.com takes me to a simple page that contains little more than: "Windows Update is included in Control Panel. To check for updates:  Click the Start button, click All Programs, and then click Windows Update." and two screenshots illustrating same.

Comment: I have different XP edition on my different machine and it works fine there I can't use that XP because it has some error

Comment: Message "Windows Update is included in Control Panel. To check for updates: Click the Start button, click All Programs, and then click Windows Update." is only for Windows Vista+

Answer (score 3):

The Windows update site was decommissioned on 3 August 2020 for XP computers.

> Most users will not be impacted by this change. Starting with Windows 8 Desktop and Windows Server 2012, connections to Windows Update service endpoints use a more modern algorithm (SHA-256). Older versions of Windows connect to Windows Update service endpoints by using the less secure SHA-1 algorithm.

Source: [Windows Update SHA-1 based endpoints discontinued for older Windows devices](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4569557/windows-update-sha-1-based-endpoints-discontinued)

You will need to use the Windows catalog and download updates manually.

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=xp%20sp3

Answer (score 0):

Official support for Windows XP SP3 ended at April 8, 2014. So you can no longer use Windows Update to install updates. Instead visit [Microsoft Update catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Windows%20XP%20Sp3) and install updates you need. Or use Autopatcher.